# save store on Android device with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to do a "save" and "restore" function for my game on Android (Adobe AIR).

So far, It seems to work for saving the game, but for I've got an error for the loading.

Here's what I did,

```
        public function save(e){
    //Save data in local memory
                if(useShared){
                    shared = SharedObject.getLocal("myApp");
                    shared.data[saveNum] = jsonSave;
                    shared.flush();
                }

        private function restore(e){
if (useShared){
                // Get data from local memory
                shared = SharedObject.getLocal("myApp");
                if(shared.data[saveNum]){
                    trace("Restoring: " + shared.data[saveNum]);
                    allSaveData = new Object;
                    allSaveData = JSON.stringify(shared.data[saveNum]);
                }
            }
```

Between I put all the information needed (player's current location...etc).

Did I make a mistake in my functions ?

Thank you for your help,

EDIT :

If I click on "save" everything seems to work, but if then I can't load my game. In debug mode I've got this error :
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property datetime not found on String and there is no default value.
    at com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca::SaveRestore/populateSaves()[C:\Users\Stéphan\Desktop\18 aout\La Brousse en folie tactile\com\laserdragonuniversity\alpaca\SaveRestore.as:76]
    at com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca::SaveRestore/showSaver()[C:\Users\Stéphan\Desktop\18 aout\La Brousse en folie tactile\com\laserdragonuniversity\alpaca\SaveRestore.as:149]
    at com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca::Toolbar/showSaver()[C:\Users\Stéphan\Desktop\18 aout\La Brousse en folie tactile\com\laserdragonuniversity\alpaca\Toolbar.as:129]

Here's all my code for the save/restore function.

```
package com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca {

    import flash.events.*;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class SaveRestore extends MovieClip {

        private var inv:Inventory;
        private var puzzle:Puzzle;
        private var player:Player;
        private var back:Background;
        private var options:Options;
        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var shared:SharedObject;
        private var useExternalFile:Boolean = false; //Set this to false if you don't want to deal with server-side scripts
        private var useShared:Boolean = true; // Set this to false if you don't want to use Flash player's local memory
        private var exLoader:URLLoader;
        private var exReq:URLRequest;
        private var saveURL:String;
        private var saveID:String;
        private var userID:String;
        private var checkDialog:MovieClip;
        private var slotsTaken:Array = new Array(false, false, false);
        private var currentEvent;
        private var confirm:MovieClip;

        private var allSaveData:Object;

        public function SaveRestore(stageRef:Stage, saveURL:String, saveID:String) {

            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            this.saveURL = saveURL;
            this.saveID = saveID;

            switchSave.gotoAndStop("on");
            switchRestore.gotoAndStop("off");

            // Un-comment this if you want save data to be cleared each time the SWF is opened
            // Probably only necessary for testing purposes
            //shared = SharedObject.getLocal(saveID);
            //shared.clear();

            populateSaves();

            restore1.visible = false;
            restore2.visible = false;
            restore3.visible = false;

            checkDialog = new saveOverwrite;
            addChild(checkDialog);
            checkDialog.visible = false;

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, setUpListeners);
        }

        public function populateSaves(){
            if(useExternalFile){
                // Here's where you can grab data from external .js files if you choose. This will require the use of server-side scripts
            } else if(useShared){
                shared = SharedObject.getLocal("myApp");
                var saveNum:String;
                var shotNum:String;
                for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
                    saveNum = "save" + i;
                    if (shared.data[saveNum]){
                        slotsTaken[i-1] = true;
                        var thisSave = JSON.stringify(shared.data[saveNum]);
                        this[saveNum].savedetail.text = thisSave.datetime;
                        this["restore"+i].savedetail.text = thisSave.datetime;

                        // Use a MovieClip of the background as a screenshot
                        var bg:Object = fakeScreenshot(thisSave.playerLoc.room);
                        this["save"+i].addChild(bg.bg);
                        this["save"+i].addChild(bg.bgmask);

                        var bg2:Object = fakeScreenshot(thisSave.playerLoc.room);
                        this["restore"+i].addChild(bg2.bg);
                        this["restore"+i].addChild(bg2.bgmask);

                    }
                }

            }
        }

        public function setUpListeners(e){
            switchSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoSave, false, 0, true);
            switchSave.buttonMode = true;
            switchRestore.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoRestore, false, 0, true);
            switchRestore.buttonMode = true;

            save1.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, overwriteCheck, false, 0, true);
            save2.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, overwriteCheck, false, 0, true);
            save3.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, overwriteCheck, false, 0, true);


            restore1.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restore, false, 0, true);
            restore2.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restore, false, 0, true);
            restore3.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restore, false, 0, true);

            checkDialog.canceller.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cancelled, false, 0, true);
            checkDialog.saver.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, overwrite, false, 0, true);


            closer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeSaver, false, 0, true);
            addEventListener("closeThis", closeSaver);
        }

        public function gotoSave(e){
            gotoAndStop("save");
            switchSave.gotoAndStop("on");
            switchRestore.gotoAndStop("off");

            restore1.visible = false;
            restore2.visible = false;
            restore3.visible = false;

            save1.visible = true;
            save2.visible = true;
            save3.visible = true;
        }

        public function gotoRestore(e){
            gotoAndStop("restore");
            switchSave.gotoAndStop("off");
            switchRestore.gotoAndStop("on");

            restore1.visible = true;
            restore2.visible = true;
            restore3.visible = true;

            save1.visible = false;
            save2.visible = false;
            save3.visible = false;
        }

        public function showSaver(){
            if(checkDialog.visible){
                checkDialog.visible = false;
            }
            populateSaves();
            visible = true;
            Engine.playerControl = false;
            gotoSave(null);
        }

        public function overwriteCheck(e){
            currentEvent = e;
            var parentBtn = e.target.parent.name;
            var slotNum = parentBtn.substr(parentBtn.length-1, 1);
            if (slotsTaken[slotNum-1]){
                trace("Save taken, confirming overwrite");
                checkDialog.visible = true;
            } else {
                save(e);
            }
        }

        public function cancelled(e){
            showSaver();
        }

        public function overwrite(e){
            save(currentEvent);
        }

        public function save(e){
            puzzle = Engine.puzzle;
            inv = Engine.inv;
            player = Engine.player;
            back = Engine.back;
            options = Engine.options;

            var saveNum:String = e.target.parent.name;

            //Get the status of all the puzzles
            allSaveData = new Object;
            allSaveData.puzzleStatus = new Object;
            allSaveData.puzzleStatus = puzzle.returnPuzzles();

            //Get the inventory
            allSaveData.allInv = new Array();
            var allItems =  inv.returnItems("all");
            for (var i in allItems){
                if(allItems[i].displayName){
                    //trace ("Saving " + allItems[i]);
                    allSaveData.allInv.push(allItems[i].displayName);
                }
            }
            allSaveData.currentInv = new Array();
            var currentItems = inv.returnItems(null);
            for (i in currentItems){
                allSaveData.currentInv.push([currentItems[i].displayName, currentItems[i].lookTag]);
            }

            //Get the player's current location
            allSaveData.playerLoc = new Object;
            allSaveData.playerLoc.x = player.x;
            allSaveData.playerLoc.y = player.y;
            allSaveData.playerLoc.scaleX = player.scaleX;
            allSaveData.playerLoc.room = back.currentBack.name;

            //Get the settings
            allSaveData.optset = options.saveOptions();

            // Get the date and time
            var thisDate = new Date;
            var dateString = thisDate.toLocaleString();
            allSaveData.datetime = dateString;

            var jsonSave = JSON.stringify(allSaveData);
            trace("Saving: " + jsonSave);

            //Save data in local memory
            if(useShared){
                shared = SharedObject.getLocal("myApp");
                shared.data[saveNum] = jsonSave;
                shared.flush();
            }

            if(useExternalFile){
                // Here's where you can post the data to a server-side script and save it as an external .js file
                // The trick would be to figure out how to distinguish one user from another
                // Either by creating login functionality, or just identifying by IP or something like that 
            }

            //Update save info
            e.target.parent.savedetail.text = dateString;
            showConfirm("saved", saveNum.substr(saveNum.length-1, 1));
            dispatchEvent(new Event("closeThis"));
        }

        private function restore(e){
            puzzle = Engine.puzzle;
            inv = Engine.inv;
            player = Engine.player;
            back = Engine.back;
            options = Engine.options;

            var parentBtn = e.target.parent.name;
            var slotNum = parentBtn.substr(parentBtn.length-1, 1);
            var saveNum = "save" + slotNum;
            trace(saveNum);

            Engine.restoring = true;

            allSaveData = null;

            if(useExternalFile){
                // Get data from external .js file
            } else if (useShared){
                // Get data from local memory
                shared = SharedObject.getLocal("myApp");
                if(shared.data[saveNum]){
                    trace("Restoring: " + shared.data[saveNum]);
                    allSaveData = new Object;
                    allSaveData = JSON.stringify(shared.data[saveNum]);
                }
            }

            // Restore game data
            if(allSaveData){
                puzzle.restorePuzzles(allSaveData.puzzleStatus);
                inv.restoreInv(allSaveData.currentInv, allSaveData.allInv);
                options.restoreOptions(allSaveData.optset);

                Engine.newBack = allSaveData.playerLoc.room;
                addEventListener("repose", reposePlayer);
                stageRef.dispatchEvent(new Event("changeBackground"));
                showConfirm("restored", slotNum);
                dispatchEvent(new Event("closeThis"));
            } else {
                trace ("No save data found");
                Engine.restoring = false;
            }

        }

        private function fakeScreenshot(bgName:String):Object{
            // Flash's local memory is too small to contain real screenshots, so we can fake it by creating an instance of the background
            var fakeShot:Object = new Object;
            var bgRef = getDefinitionByName(bgName);
            var bg = new bgRef;

            // Remove all the interface junk from the background movieclip
            for (var c = 0; c < bg.numChildren; ++c){
                var thisChild = bg.getChildAt(c);
                if (thisChild.name.search("_L") != -1 || 
                    thisChild.name.search("_U") != -1 || 
                    thisChild.name.search("_G") != -1 || 
                    thisChild.name.search("_T") != -1 ){ 

                    if (thisChild.usePoint)
                        thisChild.usePoint.visible = false;
                }
                if(thisChild.name.search("_O") != -1){
                    thisChild.usePoint.visible = false;
                    thisChild.depthSplit.visible = false;
                    thisChild.nodeUL.visible = false;
                    thisChild.nodeUR.visible = false;
                    thisChild.nodeLR.visible = false;
                    thisChild.nodeLL.visible = false;
                }
                if (thisChild.name.search("EXIT") != -1)
                    thisChild.visible = false;

                if (thisChild.name.search("startPoint") != -1)
                    thisChild.visible = false;
            }

            bg.scaleX = .1;
            bg.scaleY = .1;
            bg.x = 10;
            bg.y = 5;

            var bgmask:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
            bgmask.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, .5);
            bgmask.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 70, 45);
            bgmask.graphics.endFill();
            bgmask.x = bg.x;
            bgmask.y = bg.y;
            bg.mask = bgmask;

            fakeShot.bg = bg;
            fakeShot.bgmask = bgmask;

            return fakeShot;

        }

        private function reposePlayer(e){
            player = Engine.player;
            player.x = allSaveData.playerLoc.x;
            player.y = allSaveData.playerLoc.y;
            player.scaleX = allSaveData.playerLoc.scaleX;
        }

        private function showConfirm(type:String, slot){
            confirm = null;
            confirm = new MovieClip;
            confirm.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, .75);
            confirm.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 200, 25, 10);
            confirm.graphics.endFill();

            stageRef.addChild(confirm);

            var conftext:TextField = new TextField();
            conftext.text =  "Game " + type + " at slot " + slot;

            var format1:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format1.font = "Arial";
            format1.size = 18;
            format1.color = 0xFFFFFF;
            conftext.setTextFormat(format1);

            conftext.width = confirm.width - 5;
            conftext.x = 5;

            confirm.addChild(conftext);
            confirm.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeConf);

        }

        private function fadeConf(e){
            if (confirm.alpha > 0){
                confirm.alpha -= .05;
            } else {
                confirm.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeConf);
                stageRef.removeChild(confirm);
            }
        }

        private function closeSaver(e):void{
            visible = false;
            Engine.playerControl = true;
            Engine.toolbar.dispatchEvent(new Event("closedWindow"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what is the error. Is this it all the code that you thing produces the error?. If there is more code, please post it.

Comment: No one ?...Gaston F ?

Comment: I think that the error message says it all, i suppose that the code `var thisSave = JSON.stringify(shared.data[saveNum])` are inserting in the var thisSave a **string** object, then, in the next line, `thisSave.datetime` produces the error because datetime is not a property from string. Can you debug this code?